# Using multiple AngularJS versions in a project with Bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I've been trying to upgrade medium sized project from Angular version **1.2.16** to **1.6.4**. The problem here is, I can't jump from one version to another, so I have to use both versions at the same time in the project. However, I couldn't able to find a well prepared guide to follow. There are some different steps which is described in **SO** or in **Github** pages. But anyhow, I couldn't manage it.

Here are some SO links that I've been reading during this time.

1 - [Multiple versions of AngularJS in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537960/multiple-versions-of-angularjs-in-one-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

2 - [Supporting Multiple Versions of AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108084/supporting-multiple-versions-of-angularjs)

3 -  https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/How-to-use-a-different-version-of-AngularJS-using-Bower

And below is my **bower.json**:

```
{
  "name": "takademi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "angular-bindonce": "~0.3.1",
    "restangular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-base64": "~2.0.2",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Can you suggest any good guide, blog, video tutorial for me to follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, then any good idea? @Phil

Comment: this is a truly terrible idea. just upgrade to the latest version man.

Comment: Why can't you *"jump from one version to another"*? If your aim is to migrate your apps from AngularJS 1.2 to 1.6, why are you attempting to run multiple versions instead of performing the upgrade?

Comment: There is no fullproof solution to this. Try to narrow down your problem by posting the errors you're facing, and may someone be able to help you then.

Comment: I can't jump from 1.2 to 1.6, because it is a medium sized project which is very close to be a big sized one. And I am the only person who is going to handle with this project. So I have to deploy at least some parts of it piece by piece to let others not affected. Because there is such a huge risk if I upgrade from 1.2 to 1.6 in one step, it will take so long, and there will be hell to solve bugs on my own (tons of customers are using the project). So running multiple versions is the answer for me here.

Comment: What are your build tools? Do you use webpack or something?

Comment: How do you import angular now? Show some code examples